# Swap line text in sublime text 3

Tags: text, sublimetext3, swap

I'm not sure if I should ask this question on this forum or not but here we go: so lets say I got multiple lines as the following example:

```
something1:somethin2
something3:something4
something5:something6
```

How would I do to swap the first piece of text before the two dots with the one after the two dots if lets say I had around 1000 lines?

Comment: take a look at this package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Swap%20Selections

Comment: thank you, ill look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^:]+):(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2:$1`
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNcheck case sensitive*
- *check Wrap*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (         : start group 1
    [^:]+   : 1 or more character that is not colon
  )         : end group 1
  :         : literally a colon
  (         : start group 2
    .+      : 1 or more any character
  )         : end group 2
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          : content of group 2 (ie. everything that is after the colon)
:
$1          : content of group 1 (ie. everything that is before the colon)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
somethin2:something1
something4:something3
something6:something5
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!